# How to save data to a Django model in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create an e-commerce site (CS50 Project 2) that allows the user to add a listing, created through the Listings Model, to their WatchList. I am using a Django form with a Boolean field. I need help saving the listing to the WatchList Model. Also, since there will be more than one WatchList because of the multiple users, should I implement Sessions, and if so, how do I do that?

views.py

```py
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
   
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
  
    if watchlist_form.is_valid():
        watchlist = watchlist_form.save(commit=False)
        watchlist.user = request.user
        watchlist.save()
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
            "auction_listing": listing,
            "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
            "auction_listing": listing,
            "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
        })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing
        "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
    })
```

models.py

```py
class Listings(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
    ("Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous"),
    ("Movies and Television", "Movies and Television"),
    ("Sports", "Sports"),
    ("Arts and Crafts", "Arts and Crafts"),
    ("Clothing", "Clothing"),
    ("Books", "Books"),
]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000000000, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

class WatchList(models.Model):
    listing = models.ManyToManyField(Listings)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    add_to_watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

watchlist views.py

```
def watchlist(request):
    watchlist = WatchList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    get_listings = watchlist.listings.all()
    listings = get_listings.objects.all()
    #listings = [listings.title for listings in watchlist.objects.all()]
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html",{
        "listings": listings
    })
```

fixed views.py

```
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
        if watchlist_form.is_valid():
            new_watchlist_listing = watchlist.listings.add(listing)
            WatchList.add_to_watchlist = True
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                "auction_listing": listing,
                "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                "auction_listing": listing,
                "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
    })
```

Comment: Do you want users to be able to have multiple watchlists? The model design would be different based on this.

If not, currently the naming is confusing because it's called WatchList but technically it represents a watchlist item. You don't need a boolean field. If the object is created, that implies it's added to the watchlist. You would never create a watchlist item unless it was added if that makes sense.

Sessions aren't necessary, your watched items can be associated with the user using the user foreign key field.

You have to use add() to add the listing item to the watchlist.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ for how to add manytomany relationships

Comment: @wjh18, I want the user to be able to have only one watchlist. Currently, I have a boolean field in a django form for the user to check mark. How else could I know if they wanted to add the listing to their watchlist? Also, does the fact that I am added a model (Listings) into another model (WatchList) complicate adding it?

Comment: Your form fields don't need to line up with your model fields. And not every form needs to be a model form. Designing a model with an unnecessary field simply to include that field in a model form doesn't make much sense. Ask yourself if you would use that field for any other reason. In this case, the answer would be no because you could query the watchlist objects for a user and it would accomplish the same thing. Sure, the MtM complicates it more than if you were to just run `{Model}.objects.create()`. But you want the right relationships design so later on your querying is easier.

Comment: @wjh18, if I don't use a model form, how will I know if the use wants to add the listing to their watchlist and if I can't run ```{Model}.objects.create()```, then what do I run? Is the current way I have the Many to Many relationship fine or should I change it?

Comment: See my answer below, there's not enough room here to fully explain

Comment: @wjh18, I was able to save the watchlists, but when I try to query for all the listings through the watchlist (added watchlist views.py), I receive an error ```'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'listings'```  from ```get_listings = watchlist.listings.all() ```. Also, the checkmark that the user marks to add a listing to the watchlist disappears when they go to another page in the application. I added this line of code: ```WatchList.add_to_watchlist = True```, but it is still happening. Do you know how to fix this because I need to allow the user to remove the item from the watchlist?

Comment: Look into `related_name`, default managers (`articles_set` in this case) and relationships in general. I answered the original question so I suggest opening a new one / accepting the answer if it was helpful.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: @wjh18, today I realized that other parts of my web application were not working. I fixed the parts that were previously working, but now I am receiving this error ```'function' object has no attribute 'listings'``` because of this line of code ```new_watchlist_listing = watchlist.listings.add(listings)```. Do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like `watchlist.listing.add(listing)` in your form after the watchlist has been saved. Read the docs I linked earlier, there are many examples there.

I would change the name of the ManyToManyField to `listings` though because `watchlist.listings.add(listing)` is better solely from a naming standpoint. There could be many listings not just one. Even when you query for listings from a watchlist doing `watchlist.listings.all()` reads better than `watchlist.listing.all()`.

You should also check in your view whether it's a `POST` request before creating your bound form and determining if it's valid. If it's not a `POST`, you want to create your unbound form (form with no data associated with it yet). Right now your unbound form is being overridden by your bound form because it uses the same variable and is assigned right before it. Another reason to perform that `POST` check.

Overriding part:

```
watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
```

I won't write the whole code for you because you'll learn more by experimenting with it, but here's a general overview:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Create bound form, check if form is valid, add the listing to the watchlist, and perform any other form processing logic
else:
    # Create the unbound form so on a GET request, the unbound form is shown to the user
```